# How can I Boolean(Disable/Enable) SetActive MY Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I need have Boolean SetActive for example i want setActice false a Object and next i want setActice true it but when i playing my game and first setactive false my object (boy.max) i can not return my object even my set Active will be true

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Hidden : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initializatio
// Update is called once per frame
void Update(){
    if(Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")){
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log("Remove");
    }
    if(Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire2")){
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log("Return");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my problems video:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-1NrBmZJDU2LWwyZlloNll4NWs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you disable a `GameObject` all of its components stop running. This includes the script telling it to turn itself back on again. How does it read the information to turn back on when its not reading any information at all? For this reason you have to disable it from outside of itself.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HideObject : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject objectToHide;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update(){
    if(Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")){
        objectToHide.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log("Remove");
    }
    if(Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire2")){
        objectToHide.SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log("Return");
        }
    }
}
```